# Any minimal or night view or overlay for google maps api v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The default overlays that come out of the box for Google Maps API v3 Street, terrain, etc. appear to busy. I want to have a good "night" or "minimal" overlay that is like leaflet night view or minimal view http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html (select the layer control to switch between views) or a simple white and gray map without all the business of the colors. Are there such overlays that exist or settings that could be used so that I could use it/customize it for my Google Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own style.  Here is the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Included is a style wizard that generates all the JSON for you

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html